# How to handle boss' request to invite potential future employees

Tags: professionalism, recruitment, new-hires

The last six months I've been an intern at a tech company and I've been offered, and have accepted a job. Now my contract is for eight hours a week since I'm still going to college for another year and a half.

My boss asked me if I could introduce/reccomend a fellow student who would like a paid job like mine to do certain tasks within the company.

I know two students who live relatively close to the company and are serious enough for a job. But I don't know their level in coding, since I've only known them for a year before the internship.

I simply don't know if they're upto the job, and don't want to look stupid, and might lose trust for a future full-time job opportunity when one of them know too little to be able to perform on the job.

> How should I handle this situation professionally?

**Am I overthinking this too much?*

Comment: No company will accept the recommendation of an intern. You can just say you know them, but you cannot *recommend* them. So yes, you're overthinking.

Comment: Related, possible duplicates: "[How well do you have to know someone to refer them to your company?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/63422/how-well-do-you-have-to-know-someone-to-refer-them-to-your-company)" and "[Referring someone I don't know, but recomended by someone I trust](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/44799/referring-someone-i-dont-know-but-recomended-by-someone-i-trust)"

Comment: @cst1992 - That is quite a sweeping statement. Some companies do

Comment: @cst1992 my boss explicitly asked me to recommend someone, but yes I do agree and see that I'm overthinking this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just say to your manager that you know of two students that would be interested but you cannot vouch for their competency. At the end of the day it is up to the person doing the hiring to figure that bit out.

Also just get the two people that you have in mind to write to your boss.

Comment: @Styphon The edit facility is there, you can submit the edit yourself.

Comment: @cst1992 I tried, it's too small an edit.

Comment: @Styphon yeah, that's a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would speak to your boss and just tell him the truth,
so tell him that you know 2 young programmer, but since you don't know them very well you can't confirm their coding level.

follow this way tell your boss that you are conscious about the risk, and you are responsible and trustable.